# Convert HTML to image on Apple Watch?

Tags: swift, watchos

I'm trying to get the HTML of a website, and display it as a picture. The conversion is very straightforward on iOS, but since watchOS doesn't have WKWebView (which all of the methods I've found uses) I can't use those solutions.

I've also explored doing it via an API, but they're either too costly or look suspicious (but please feel free to point me to one if you're aware of one!).

Is there any way to display HTML as an image on Apple Watch?

Thanks!

Comment: you could try to render it on a server and then serve the resulting image

Comment: Good idea! I'm exploring setting up an AWS server and a Swift API to get this working, thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deploy your own free microservice (i.e. with node.js + heroku) and then make the http request to your service passing your url and getting back your image.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! I'm now planning to write a Swift microservice API and deploy it on an AWS server. :)